# XElement write numeric character reference

Tags: android, xml, special-characters, xelement, ncr

I'm trying to write a strings.xml file for our android app via a resource provider from our translation tool.

So the procedure is like this:
-Start translation tool and import strings.xml
-Do the translations
-Use the custom resource provider to export strings.xml
-Import strings.xml to android project

The strings.xml file has the following structure:
Send data. Please wait…

As you can see, the char … (Ellipsis) is written as &#8230 (NCR).
Android needs it to be like this.

Now to my problem, the translation tool saves the Ellipsis as char … and not as &#8230. I then customized the resource adapter to Replace("…","&#8230")

But now my XML File looks like this:
Send data. Please wait&#8230;

So it's replacing the char & with &

Is there a possibility to make an XElement with &#8230 as value?

Comment: No, there isn't. Can't you just replace it when you are reading the xml? An example: `element.Value.Replace("&amp;", "&")`.

Comment: Hi, ok sad to hear but thank you for your answer! I'll try to replace it when reading the XML file